# Table column data organization not correct - latex

Tags: tables, xetex

I am new in latex. I have created a table. However, it is not what I expected.

[image]

I expected it to be centered and well separated such as the following (this table is constructed in MS Word),

[image]

```
\begin{table}[htb] % <--- "here", "top", "bottom"
\centering
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
\caption{Sample result of N. UzZaman and Mumit’s Bangla soundex table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} lcc @{}}
    \toprule
    \toprule
\makecell[lb]{Input}
            & \makecell[b]{Encoded}
                                & \makecell[b]{Suggestion}\\
    \midrule
\textbengali{খুমাড়}  & kumar        & \textbengali{কুমার}\\
\textbengali{পাসান}  & pasan        & \textbengali{পাষাণ}\\
    \bottomrule
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
  \label{table3}
\end{table}
```

Since the document size is huge, I am unable to post the whole code here. I have added the following packages I used.

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{bengali}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Vrinda}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

Comment: You should not post the whole document, you should not post the long list of used packages also. You should post a minimal code only, with related packages and commands, which is called an [MWE](http://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/156344).

Comment: For future posts please try to use accurate tags for your question. I notice that many of your questions (indeed all six) were initially tagged with `biblatex`, `bibtex` even though they had nothing to do with bibliographies in general and `biblatex` and BibTeX specifically. You don't have to add a lot of tags to your question, but please try to find ones that accurately describes what your question is about and avoid misusing tags that have nothing to do with the question as such.

Comment: @JouleV Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @moewe Please suggest me some tags I can use for latex problems. I thought biblatex bibtex are just another names of latex

Comment: @NahidHossain There is no general tag for LaTeX problem, because obviously this site is for LaTeX only ;) For example, about tables, you have [tag:table], about drawing, [tag:diagram] or [tag:tikz-pgf] or [tag:pstricks] or something, etc.

Comment: `biblatex` and BibTeX are not other names for LaTeX. `bibtex` is a particular program (and by extension ecosystem) for bibliographies. `biblatex` is a different package for bibliographies. Usually it is implied on this site that your are asking about LaTeX (if you were to ask about a different *TeX, you would use a particular tag: `context` or `plain-tex`). It is more important to tag your question with the topic you are asking about: In this case `tables`. All of your questions have ben re-tagged, just check out the new tags to get a feel what you could use.

Comment: Now to your question: `l` and `c` table headings only take up natural space and don't spread to fill the available space if they don't have to. With `tabularx` you want to use at least one `X`-type column. Try something like `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} XXX @{}}` instead of `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} lcc @{}}`.

Comment: BTW: You can find out more about tags by clicking on them and then going to the *info* tab. For `tables` you find https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/tables/info, for `biblatex` https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/biblatex/info. When you tag your question there are usually little explanatory texts that tell you what each suggested tag is about: Read that before you decide whether or not to include the tag. Using the right tags increases the chance of having the right people look at your question.

Comment: @moewe Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{Sample result of N. UzZaman and Mumit’s Bangla soundex table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{LCC}
    \toprule
\makecell[lb]{Input}
        & \makecell[b]{Encoded}
                    & \makecell[b]{Suggestion}\\
    \midrule
some bengali text %\textbengali{খুমাড়}
    & kumar         & some bengali text \\  %\textbengali{কুমার}\\
some bengali text %\textbengali{পাসান}
    & pasan         & some bengali text \\  %\textbengali{পাষাণ}\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
  \label{table3}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Sample result of N. UzZaman and Mumit’s Bangla soundex table}
    \begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \toprule
\makecell[lb]{Input}
        & \makecell[b]{Encoded}
                    & \makecell[b]{Suggestion}\\
    \midrule
some bengali text %\textbengali{খুমাড়}
    & kumar         & some bengali text \\  %\textbengali{কুমার}\\
some bengali text %\textbengali{পাসান}
    & pasan         & some bengali text \\  %\textbengali{পাষাণ}\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \label{table3}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

it gives:

[image]

as mentioned in comments below your question, in `tabularx` should be at least one colum  of type `X` or derived from `X` as is used in above code (`L`, `C`).

off-topic: see if the following links is helpful to you:

- [latex in 139 minutes](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf)
- [wiki; tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables)
- [design nice tables](https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/)